# Make a self-aware menubar

Tags: php, menu, menubar

So, In the website I'm currently designing (HTML5, PHP, JS/JQuery and Bootstrap), I've got a basic menubar at the top of the page.  Just your normal

```
    <ul>
    <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="players.php">Players</a></li>
    <li><a href="rules.php">Rules</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Now, there's a lot more to this, such as a login button, etc, but basically it's adding a LOT of clutter to the top of my pages, and I was wondering if there would be any way to put it in a header.php file.
My issue is how I can use it in multiple webpages and still have the `class="active"` part.  The only thing I thought of was making a function where it takes the page name as a string and go through each line and does if (the page is the same as the link) { echo the element with the `class="active"` } else { echo the element without the class }
Thanks!

Comment: what about include() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to extract your header to header.php as you said, and then use the PHP include method.

```
<?php

include 'header.php';

?>
```

As far as selecting the 'active' class, you could pass and set an '$active' variable on each page. And then, since the included file inherits the scope from the page where it's included, you can get the variable and preform your logic in the header.php page.

Comment: Thanks, I already knew about include but the second paragraph was what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

You can include another php file located anywhere on your server, and have the menu html in there, in a function as you said.

As for keeping the class="active", since you already have it working somewhere, presumably in your main php file, you can just move it to the new header php file that will be included and re-factor if necessary.

I don't know what your code looks like at all, if you post part of it that does the menu, me or someone else will probably be able to help more.